# Highcharts stacked column colors keep changing

Tags: highcharts

Everytime my data updates to compare a new chart, the colors change on my stacked column chart. I want to make them static and not dynamic.

I tried setting the color in the series with the data and name, but that didn't work. I can't do a fiddle because it is making am ajax call to an outside data source. Everytime a new checkbox gets checked, another chart gets added for comparison. When this happens, the colors change.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
                var selected = [];
                $('#patient input:checked').each(function () {
                    selected.push(this.id);
                });

            $.ajax({
                url: "sampleurl",
                data: {
                    "sample": selected
                },
                success: handleData
            });
        });

var handleData = function (data) {
                //splits the data into two arrays and maps it 
                var uniq = a => [...new Set(a)];
                var flatten = a => [].concat.apply([],a);

            var samplePatient= uniq(flatten(data.results.map(e=>e._id)).map(e=>e.patient));
            var labels = uniq(flatten(data.results.map(e=>e.days)).map(e=>e.action));

            var result = labels.map(label => {
                return {
                    label,
                    data: samplePatient.map(patient => {
                        var hit = data.results.find(e => e._id.patient === patient).days
                            .find(p => p.action === label)
                        return hit ? hit.days : 0
                    })
                }
            });

            $('.container').html("");
            Highcharts.chart('container', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'column',
                    marginRight:35,
                    marginLeft:100,
                    marginBottom:50                        
                },
                 title: {
                    text: 'Sample Title'
                }, 
                xAxis: {
                    categories: patients,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Patient #'
                    }                        
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Days'
                    },
                    stackLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'},

                            formatter: function() {
                            return  Highcharts.numberFormat(this.total, 2, '.');
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    split: true,                        
                },
                colors: [
                    '#a33c3c',
                    '#e3a207',
                    '#db874e',
                    '#328692',
                    '#59397a'
                ],
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        stacking: 'normal',
                        dataLabels:{
                            enabled:true},
                        lineColor: '#666666',
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        marker: {
                            lineWidth: 1,
                            lineColor: '#666666'
                        }
                    },
                    series:{
                        groupPadding:.05
                    }
                },
                legend:{
                    layout:'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    x: 0,
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    y: 50,
                    padding: 3,
                    itemMarginTop: 5,
                    itemMarginBottom: 5,
                    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
                    borderColor: '#CCC',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    shadow: false
                },
                series: [{
                            name: result[0].label,
                            data: result[0].data
                            }, {
                            name: result[1].label,
                            data: result[1].data
                            }, {
                            name: result[2].label,
                            data: result[2].data
                            }, {
                            name: result[3].label,
                            data: result[3].data
                            },{
                            name: result[4].label,
                            data: result[4].data
                        }]
            });

        }
    });
```

data console log:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "patient": "1"
    },
    "days": [
        {
            "action": "sample text",
            "days": 87
        },
        {
            "action": "sample text2",
            "days": 4564
        },
        {
            "action": "sample text3",
            "days": 984
        },
        {
            "action": "sample text4",
            "days": 516
        },
        {
            "action": "sample text5",
            "days": 548
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id": {
        "patient": "5"
    },
    "days": [
        {
            "action": "sample text",
            "days": 5464
        },
        {
            "action": "sample text2",
            "days": 4894
        },
        {
            "action": "sample text3",
            "days": 468
        },
        {
            "action": "sample text4",
            "days": 887
        },
        {
            "action": "sample text5",
            "days": 96
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: As you said _I tried setting the color in the series with the data and name, but that didn't work_, this should work. Can you add console log of series data you are creating

Comment: I edited my original post with sample console log. The name: result[0].label is accessing the 'action' and the data: result[0].data is accessing the 'days'. Everytime I click a checkbox for a patient #, the chart appears. If I click the box again, the chart removes. This way I can choose whatever patients I want to compare at a specific time.

Comment: @user54289 Provide us with a working example using some dummy data.

Comment: @d_paul it is difficult to do that because my data is coming from ajax calls using mongo pulling from different databases. I think the issue is that everytime I click a new checkbox, new charts are created, but when I looked into the chart.addSeries option, that needs new data. So I'm unsure how to keep my colors static everytime.

Comment: Maybe try to set colors globally with `Highcharts.setOptions` 
 function(http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Highcharts.setOptions). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fp2uo8Lh/

Comment: No luck with that either. I edited in my original post how I am handling the data after the ajax call under var handledata

Comment: I'm actually seeing now that the numbers at the bottom on my axis are changing too. So it isn't that the colors are the problem, the data is changing dynamically and I just want it to loop through